# Is it possible to do conditional handler in AMP?

Tags: amp-html, amp-animation

I need to show/hide menu only using amp-animation. I created two different amp-animations `showMenu` and `hideMenu`. My first attempt was to do something like that

```
<div on="tap:AMP.setState({ menu: { open: !menu.open }}),menu.open ? hideMenu : showMenu">
```

Which didn't work because apparently you cannot put conditional logic on top level but can inside `setState` function. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Can you give us more information as to what you are trying to accomplish with the two amp-animations?

Comment: Sure, I want to implement simple toggling